# Installing GarageBand on OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, garageband

I've recently downgraded to 10.8.5 as I had been having trouble getting Mavericks to work with my TASCAM US-1641 audio interface. I tried to reinstall GarageBand and try out my interface again only to find that the version of GarageBand in the App Store is only for Mavericks. Is there any way to download an old version? Which version would I need for Mountain Lion? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found another Macbook that already had GarageBand running on and copied GarageBand right out of the Applications folder and into the shared folder of my newer computer that needed it.  My new machine also runs Mountain Lion.  Once it's in the shared folder of the new computer, then move it to the Applications folder of the new computer.

Comment: You might also look in /Library/Application Support/GarageBand for loops to copy. Most installations have about 5 GB of samples there from that era of Garage Band program.

Comment: also, there is often an old version of Garageband on computers that have upgraded. Mine was moved into a folder "Garageband 6.0.5"